# Reading Facebook page settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an app that lets the user post to Facebook pages. Before posting, I'd like to check if the page allows photo posts (or if it allows posts at all). 
The `/v2.2/{page-id}/settings` resource requires a page access token, which I don't have since I'm not the owner of the pages.

Is there a way to read these settings in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page#readfields:

> **can_post**:
>   Whether the current session user can post on this Page.

---

Whether or not the current user is specifically allowed to post photos to a page, that you can’t query as far as I know – so you’ll just have to try, and check what response you get.

Comment: Thanks, how about the permission to post photos? That's my main concern.

Comment: That you can’t query as far as I know – so you’ll just have to try, and check what response you get. Btw., an app that allows users to post to random pages they don’t own might be close to spamming, so be careful how that feature gets used.